# What were the typical game development toolchains for the pre-i386 IBM PC era

Tags: ms-dos, gaming, software-development, compilers

On i386 and beyond (assuming MS-DOS as the target OS and IBM PC as the target platform), my impression is game developers most typically used Watcom C / DJGPP plus one of the DOS extenders (DOS4GW, cwsdpmi etc.) plus graphics libraries such as SVGAKit or Allegro.

I wonder what were the most used toolchains (compiler, runtime if any, libraries) for the i286 era? In particular, did games typically use the 16-bit protected mode, and if so, was there something like a "16-bit DOS extender"? Or, rather, was using EMS / XMS sufficient?

I recall Borland had DPMI16BI.OVL, but it's a question if Borland was the compiler vendor of choice for game developers back in the day, and even if it was, whether the game developers used the Borland's DPMI?

Comment: Isn't that a bit broad? Answers might be rather opinion and random data points. Also, original game development for the PC was rather limited before the 386 and not really standardized to a few tools like today. Language choice was Pascal or Assembly - or even BASIC - C was only creeping in slowly. Most 'big' games were ports from other platforms, usually done in assembly for speed reasons - remember those boxes were slower than Amigas or Ataris.

Comment: Plus in the 286 era machines were still relatively expensive. Which means that well into the 286 era there were plenty of people still running XTs with varying amounts of memory from 640K (which was a reasonable expectation for the mid-1980s, but which itself varied in *usable* memory after drivers, etc.) to a couple Meg., so targeting machines with lots of EMS for games would have been a bit limiting.

Comment: And arguably the first several years of the IBM PC era were primarily targeted towards businesses large (got a mainframe, get PCs to go with it) and small (nobody was ever fired for buying IBM). For much of the 80s, if you were a real gamer you got a machine that came with better graphics and sound capabilities (Atari, Amiga, etc.) or a longer history and therefore more game software despite the limitations (Apple ][). The people buying PC/XT/AT - until the clone market really took off and prices dropped - were largely buying for business and games secondary. A business could justify spending

Comment: a lot for a big EMS card. A gamer would be better off getting a machine better designed for games in the first place. It was really the 386 era - with lower machine prices *and* a lot more memory - that made the change.

Comment: For a little context for Watcom C, the reason you saw DOS/4GW and Watcom C everywhere before DJGPP came around was cost. It was significantly more expensive to buy something else *and* a DPMI extender than just to buy Watcom C and get the pack-in version of DOS/4G for Watcom. Sure, Watcom's developer documentation wasn't as good, and it was artificially limited (to using 16MiB of RAM IIRC) unless you bought the Pro upgrade, but it was affordable and game developers had moved to Windows 95 by the time they could rely on customers having that much RAM.

Comment: @Raffzahn opinions and random data points would also be helpful because I virtually have no idea of how the game development landscape looked like in late 80s - very early 90s. In particular, while I can imagine smaller titles such as Tower Toppler or Alley Cat having been programmed in assembly, I can hardly imagine larger ones (think Wolfenstein 3D or Duck Tales) being programmed without use of higher level languages.

Comment: @Raffzahn Re "C was only creeping in slowly" - here, I wonder which (approximately) point in time this refers to. Being a teenager in early 1990s, I clearly remember I was told by someone knowledgeable that C was *the* language for creating computer games. This boosted my interest in learning C considerably, and eventually I could program in C before I started learning Pascal in college :) ). Tools wise, I remember there were Turbo C++ from Borland and Quick C from Microsoft - but that's what was popular among hobbyists. Not sure if professional programmers used the same tools though.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I agree my perception might be a bit skewed. Where I grew up, what most people could afford at home in the early 90s were ZX Spectrum clones at best.  On the other hand, thanks to the IBM PC clone market booming, XT and AT machines started appearing at work, which, in turn, prompted interest to exactly PC gaming (in many places, management was mostly OK with recreational use of the office PCs during launch break / during after hours).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact So, while I totally understand your point regarding large amounts of EMS memory being too expensive (and, hence, rare), I believe PC AT machines with 2 MB of memory were nothing extraordinary around 1991-1992 even where I live. But the point I am probably missing that the majority of the games targeting IBM PC AT had been created in the late 80s, when 640 KB should have been enough for anyone

Comment: @DmytroL same tools everywhere, after all, game programmers started more often than not out as hobbyists and kept their tools. MS was what most non game professionals used. And Watcom apealed to game and non game. And as you say, that was the 1990s, a time when the 286 was already on the way out and C on the way in - no wonder he told you it's the coming language. Much like electric cars today. Everyone talks about, everyone wants, but in reality 90% of what's on the road is gas guzzling.

Comment: @DmytroL Datapoints: You may have noticed that introduction of the PC used to happen at different speed with different targets in various parts of the world. Without implication, but at the time a 286 seemed a good choice in your area, it was not even an entry choice in other laces. Also, what has a HLL to do with game size? Language choice, especially with a simple one as C, has a neglectable impact on larger projects. It's all about tools and libraries that build the game engine - all of them usually DIY at that time. Also the reason why Unity rules today.

Comment: @Raffzahn Re HLL and game size: I'd assume that use of a HLL vs. assembly directly correlates with developer productivity. IMHO even such a simple language as C adds more structure to the code and reduces cognitive load when reasoning about the code compared to pure assembly language. Especially in larger projects where the game engine itself is anything but trivial. This is not to neglect the value of tools and libraries, though even there use of HLL could offer productivity benefits unless we're talking about something really performance-critical.

Comment: @DmytroL These arguments do only hold for trivial project where next to all functionality is provided by that language. Any game past a text based number guessing will be more complex than that. Assembly does not generate more 'cognitive' load then any other language (I would think figuring out parentheses in C is way more challenging). Also, what would that structure be assembler can not provide?

Answer (score 9):

There did exist extenders for the 286, like DOS/4G's sibling, [DOS/16M](https://web.archive.org/web/20171109220335/http://www.tenberry.com/dos16m/index.html), but market forces meant that game developers couldn't rely on people having a 286 enough to make them worthwhile.

Like tools like QRAM ([QEMM-386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMM)'s counterpart for pre-386 machines) and LIM EMS boards themselves, they were for the business market, where it'd be justifiable to spend that kind of money to ensure that a piece of software you were buying/selling/developing in-house could economically manipulate the amount of data a business problem required.

It was "expensive, but still cheaper if we can make a microcomputer do the work of a minicomputer/mainframe" thinking.

Comment: Was there ANY profit for using 286-kind 16bit protected mode? The addressing remained effectively 16-bit and even became worse for addressing arrays of size >64kbytes (as far as I can suggest). The only real ease of memory addressing arrived with 32-bit mode in 386+ CPUs.